# How to analyse the bound of the sum of permutation sequences?

Tags: inequality

suppose $X=[x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_n]$ ($0<x_1\leq x_2\leq \ldots\leq x_n$),
and
$$f(X) = \frac{x_1+2x_2+3x_3+\ldots+nx_n}{nx_1+(n-1)x_2+(n-2)x_3+\ldots+x_n}$$
i.e.,$$f(X) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\times x_{i}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i\times x_{n-i+1}}}$$

Is there a (tight) bound for $f(X)$?

Comment: Notice the ratios of $x_i$ in numerator vs denominator $\frac{i}{n+i-i}$ are all $\le n$, we have $f(X) \le n$. If we fix $x_n$ to $1$ and send the remaining $x_i$ to $0$, we find $f(X) \to n$. This mean the limit $n$ is admissible and $n$ is a tight upper bound for $f(X)$. Is this what you want???

Comment: Right, thanks. $f(X)$ is bounded by $min(n, \frac{x_n}{x_1})$